# Batch File: If registry key's data equals x

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to check whether a recording device is enabled or disabled. I've tried a ton of examples I've found, but just can't get it to work. Both of the commands I use to change the data work.

Here's what I currently have:

```
REG QUERY "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{f2b4b04b-e32f-494a-94fc-f7846a7fc275}" /v 

"DeviceState" | Find "1"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto turnoff
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon
goto end

:turnon
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{f2b4b04b-e32f-494a-94fc-f7846a7fc275}" /v DeviceState /d 1 /t Reg_DWord /f


:turnoff
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{f2b4b04b-e32f-494a-94fc-f7846a7fc275}" /v DeviceState /d 0x10000001 /t Reg_DWord /f
goto end

:end
@exit
```

I'm not sure if the `Find "1"` should actually be 1. When I query that data and the device is enabled, the output is `DeviceState    REG_DWORD    0x1`
and while the device is disabled, the output is `DeviceState    REG_DWORD    0x10000001`

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and review [MCVE].  What is "DeviceState" ?  Program/script?

Comment: @jwdonahue DeviceState would be the hexadecimal Registry DWord that tells the state of the device (Enabled or Disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion^
\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{f2b4b04b-e32f-494a-94fc-f7846a7fc275}

reg query "%key%" /v DeviceState | find "0x10000001"
if errorlevel 1 goto turnoff
goto turnon

:turnon
reg add "%key%" /v DeviceState /d 0x1 /t REG_DWORD /f
goto :eof

:turnoff
reg add "%key%" /v DeviceState /d 0x10000001 /t REG_DWORD /f
goto :eof
```

Or shorter code without using goto:

```
set key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion^
\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{f2b4b04b-e32f-494a-94fc-f7846a7fc275}

reg query "%key%" /v DeviceState | find "0x10000001"
if errorlevel 1 (set "data=0x10000001") else set "data=0x1"
reg add "%key%" /v DeviceState /d %data% /t REG_DWORD /f
```

The use of `^` at end of line is a line continuation character i.e.
the interpreter removes the `^` and joins the next line to the current line.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` can be substituted with `HKLM` in the `reg` commands.

`goto :eof` a.k.a *goto end of file* will end the script.

**Issues in your code:**

- Commands after `:turnon` label continue on to the `:turnoff` label
  commands thus `:turnon` commands are undone.
- `find "1"`. `1` can be found in `0x1` and in `0x10000001`. Advise
  `find "0x10000001"` as it is unique to both data values.

**Note:**

I tested with `HKLM\SOFTWARE\~Microsoft\...` key instead of
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...` key as on Win7, the key of
`MMDevices` and subkeys has SYSTEM permissions set and admin
and user groups do not have permission to write.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch. You taught me a whole lot here. I had to get permissions there earlier so that wasn't an issue here.